# JQuery form validation submitHandler is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I already using this plugin. Here I am try to use `remote` concept it's also successfully validating but `submitHandler` functions is not working.(`alert("submitHandler");` not alerted)

*NOTE: I cannot submit this form if I am using the `remote` concept.
 Without `remote` concept working fine.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add-ingredients-form").validate({       
        rules: { 
            ingrediants_barcode: {  
                required: true,
                remote: {
                        url: "ajax-check-product-name.php",
                        type: "post"
                },              
            },
            product_name: {  
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "ajax-check-product-name.php",
                    type: "post"
                }               
            },
            brand_name: {  required: true },
            quantity: {  required: true },
            unit: {  required: true },
            expiry_date: {  required: true }
        }, 

        messages: {
            ingrediants_barcode: {              
                remote: "Ingrediant barcode already in use!"
            },
            product_name: {                 
                remote: "Product name already in use!"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) { 
              alert("submitHandler");//Not working
              form.submit();//Not working                       
        }
    });
});
```

**I cannot submit this form if I am using the `remote` concept.** Please update where I am wrong.

Thanks to All!

Comment: Show the server-side code for `ajax-check-product-name.php`... also where is the relevant HTML markup for this form?  By the way, you're using the same server-side script, `ajax-check-product-name.php`, for both fields... is that intentional?